# Unable to fetch the New branch in Eclipse Git Remote Tracking for one machine

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, git-commit, egit, git-push

I have an Eclipse Project which is maintained in git. After the first commit, yesterday I added new files directly to the master branch (which I later realized was wrong, and should have created a local branch). Today I tried to create a local branch on two machines and tried to push the codes on the respective machines.

**STEPS**:

1. Created a new branch in git
2. Eclipse - Git repository - Fetch from Upstream - added the new branch
3. Switched to the new branch
   and checked out
4. Making new changes to the code

On one machine I could go through these steps smoothly. I am getting stuck on the other machine at #2. I am unable to find the *Fetch from Upstream* option. I only see *Fetch from origin*, and when I click on that, system prompts "No ref to fetch".

[image: Fetch from origin]

[image: No ref to fetch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, revert to command-line, and check on both machine:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config -l
```

Try and compare in both the remote and branch section like:

```
remote.origin.url=https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

By setting them identical between the two machines repositories, you should then be able to switch back to Eclipse and see the same options again.

Comment: I haven't tried command-line for git related activities. So, would be great if you could help me out with this.
I have tried `git config -l`. Post that should I expect those commands you have mentioned.

Comment: @testingqwerty You should expect to see various settings, as described in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config, including the `remote.origin.xxx` ones I mention in the answer.